# MYSQL IF NOT NULL included in the query

Tags: mysql, sql

I couldn’t solve the problem in my own advertising publishing system.

There are “publishing_date" and "expiration_date” columns in mysql table. These columns are not required to fill (default value) and they’re in integer type.
In the mysql query, the ads will be listed normally and if this two columns are not null then they will be included in the query.

```
Example:

publishing_date < current_date < expiration_date

Table:

id|publishing_date|expiration_date
1|1450821600|1451512800  ---> 2015/12/23 - 2015/12/31
2|1464555600|1465506000  ---> 2016/05/30 - 2016/06/10
3|NULL|NULL
4|NULL|NULL
```

It should show 2, 3, 4 ids

Comment: Add sample table data, and the expected result

Comment: which data type are the publishing_date adn expiration_date columns?

Comment: data types are integer

Comment: You're making your life harder with those NULLs. Just use a fixed date, e.g. :'1970-01-01'

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly then this query should work.

```
SELECT id FROM ads WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(publishing_date, '%Y-%m-%d') < DATE(NOW()) AND FROM_UNIXTIME(expiration_date, '%Y-%m-%d') < DATE(NOW()) OR (publishing_date IS NULL AND expiration_date IS NULL)
```

Comment: Check the table name.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I solved my problem

SELECT DISTINCT id FROM ads WHERE (publishing_date IS NULL AND expiration_date IS NULL) OR (publishing_date < UNIX_TIMESTAMP() AND expiration_date > UNIX_TIMESTAMP() AND (publishing_date IS NOT NULL AND expiration_date IS NOT NULL))

Comment: Couldn't you therefore simplify it to: `SELECT DISTINCT id FROM ads WHERE (publishing_date IS NULL AND expiration_date IS NULL) OR (publishing_date < UNIX_TIMESTAMP() AND expiration_date > UNIX_TIMESTAMP())`